# Wouldn't it be possible to use just dot (.) to access members of namespace and static members of a class

Tags: c++, syntax, language-lawyer

In C++ we use double colon (`::`) to access members of namespace, use dot (`.`) to access members of class/structure and use arrow (`->`) to access members of class/structure via pointer.

Wouldn't it be possible to use just dot (`.`)? E.g. `my_namespace.my_class.my_static_pointer.my_member`. Why are separate lexemes used? Would there be any problems with syntax, if only dot (`.`) were used for all three cases?

Comment: The scope operator `::`can be used for more things than just your example, things that would get ambigious

Comment: @davidhig  Dot can not be overloaded for now.

Comment: @Oliv:ah, right, this is still a proposal

Comment: It would make a different programming language.

Comment: How would we then differentiate between a namespace and an object with automatic storage? That brings ambiguity and confusion in my opinion.

Comment: @Ron: You ought to base an answer on that. In getting all excited about the possibility of templates breaking, I forgot the obvious point.

Comment: @Ron A namespace can just be seen as a singleton object, residing in the object file! It is a kind of static object created when the object file is mapped to memory. We already do not make any difference between objects created dynamicaly, automaticaly or staticaly.

Comment: @Bathsheba I was about to but the question was sadly closed.

Comment: @Ron: It's an exact duplicate though. A good spot by the finder. There would be no harm in you putting an answer there.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree. It's a good dupe find.

Comment: Uh where did my comment go? Did it offend some mod?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I appreciate that English may well not be your first language, but one of the words you used is offensive in that language. I did warn you.

Comment: Oh well, I don't think the C++ grammar deserves any kinder words - nor that it's likely to resent my words, no matter how offensive they may be.

Comment: One more dup: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/314531/213922